# How to find Execution time of a function In Ethereum solidity REMIX-IDE

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

[As shown in figure only gas cost is given, But I have to find how much time this function will take to execute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdzZO.png)

I have tried block.timestamp function but its is not work for specific function. It give the time of a block not function execution time.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Execution time depends on the specification of the machine. In solidity, functions are executed by many machines (validators), so the execution time is not relevant.

You may look at the stack trace to compare 2 transaction's difficulties.